# How to do partial fraction decomposition with exponentials

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, summation, partial-fractions

I'm trying to separate the sum $$\sum\frac{6^j}{(3^{j+1}-2^{j+1})(3^j-2^j)}$$ into two parts so that I can use the telescoping property.  I thought I could use partial fraction decomposition and WolframAlpha supports this idea

[image]

Notice that's exactly the form I need.  However I can't figure out how they did it.  Once I get to $$6^j = 3^jA-2^jA+3^{j+1}B-2^{j+1}B$$ I'm really not sure how to continue and each way I try gets me something different (and less useful) than what WA gave.  How did WA get that result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write your numerator as $$3^{j+1}\cdot 2^j-2^{2j+1}-2^{j+1}\cdot 3^j+2^{2j+1}$$
in German "Nulladdition" i don't know the english word

Comment: Interesting.  That definitely works.  Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, we don't have a dedicated word for that idea. "Adding zero" or "add zero" or "add(ing) zero in a clever way" are commonly used.

Comment: i think adding Zero describes this very good, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Let $3^j=a,2^j=b$

$$\frac{6^j}{(3^{j+1}-2^{j+1})(3^j-2^j)}=\dfrac{ab}{(3a-2b)(a-b)}$$

Now $(3a-2b)-2(a-b)=a$ and $(3a-2b)-3(a-b)=b$

Replace the numerator $a$ or $b$ but not both with these values.